# Android, SimpleDateFormat not working

Tags: android, time, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse time only but the app code includes the date and the year.

here is my code:

```
simpleDateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
int h = Integer.parseInt(traffic.alarmClocks.get(0).get(ApplicationConstants.HOUR)); 
int m = Integer.parseInt(traffic.alarmClocks.get(0).get(ApplicationConstants.MINUTE));
String  datex2 = h + ":" + m;
Date storedalarm = simpleDateFormat2.parse(datex2);
```

output of the `datex2` is : `4:56`

Output of StoredAlarm is this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQT06.jpg

The output of the `datex2` is correct, but I need to make it into date because I am going to use it to compare times.

Comment: Probably you stored like `hh`, not `HH`, so is `04`, not `16`. `HH` will save it like `24H` and `hh` with `12H`, with `AM` and `PM`. Also, check for time zone. Do you have 12 hours difference?

Comment: if you are ignoring year, month and day, why do you need a date for comparison? can't you just compare hours and minutes?

Comment: @lelloman i'm using this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697908/check-if-a-given-time-lies-between-two-times-regardless-of-date to compare times. it requires me to parse date.

Comment: show how you format a `storedalarm` with a `simpleDateFormat2`

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin its still returning data with the date and year.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is used for formatation (eg from time-stamp to something pretty). From text to date and reverse. You can't obtain a `Date` object with just hour and minute. You can compare strings. `"string".compareTo("otherString");` is the same thing.

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin if you just need to compare hours a minutes you can set the date to 0, so all dates will have the same date 1 Jan 1970 and the comparison will be affected only by hours and minutes. but the easiest way to do this is to just compare hours and mintues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to compare times you could very easily combine hours and minutes this way:

```
int time = hours * 60 + minutes;
```

then you could just compare 2 integers.

or if you really want a Date object, you could initialize it with year, month and date to 0, and just pass hours and minutes

```
Date storedalarm = new Date(0, 0, 0, h, m);
```

in order to show just hours and minutes from your Date object you can use the same SimpleDateFormat you instantiated before

```
String formattedDate = simpleDateFormat2.format(storedalarm);
```

Comment: i need to use datex2.

Comment: what do you mean? in the code you posted `datex2` created from `h` and `m`

Comment: it's still showing the same error i'm experiencing, it still includes the month and the year. here's the full code: https://paste.ofcode.org/nxPE79bNmFjfssBwQPAvXR

Comment: of course it is showing month and year, it's a **Date** object. what is the problem? you want to show only hours and minutes from a date object?