# How can I compare two times in android?

Tags: java, android, date, time

I want to compare two times(timestamp) in my android application.
Here is my function to check whether the current time is between two given times.

```
private boolean isBetween(String t1, String t2, String target){
    boolean result = false;
    try{

        Date time1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(t1);
        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar1.setTime(time1);


        Date time2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(t2);
        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar2.setTime(time2);
        calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);


        Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(target);
        Calendar calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar3.setTime(d);
        calendar3.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

        Date x = calendar3.getTime();
        if (x.after(calendar1.getTime()) && x.before(calendar2.getTime())) {
            result = true;
            //checkes whether the current time is between 14:49:00 and 20:11:13.

            //Toast.makeText(UserCheckout.this, "The time is between", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    catch (ParseException e){
        result = false;
        Toast.makeText(UserCheckout.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is how I am using this function.

```
if (isBetween("19:00:00", "20:00:00", currentTime)){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Time is  between 7 and 8", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

if (isBetween("20:00:00", "21:00:00", currentTime)){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Time is between 8 and 9", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

But I am getting both the results true.

Comment: Have a look at `calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);` and `calendar3.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);`, because I think you're checking if `currentTime` is between 19:00 today and 20:00 tomorrow, and 20:00 today and 21:00 tomorrow, respectively.

Comment: What is the use of  `calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);` and         `calendar3.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);`? Does the API version you're coding against support Java 8? If so, maybe use Java's time api.

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke Thanku so much man. it worked.

Comment: @M.leRutte the question is flagged as Android so Java 8 features come with some caveats. That said, those APIs are probably a much better choice for tackling this problem, so using those or the ThreeTen library are indeed a much better idea

Comment: The hack is of course just to compare the strings using `String.compareTo`. It won’t be very readable, but it will work.

Comment: It seems you took the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698079/5772882). Did you read the comments to the answer too? “This probably gives the wrong answer if someRandomTime lies between string1 and "00:00:00".” And: “its showing 11:44 is inbetween 19:28 to 23:59”. Fortunately there are 17 other answers to the same question, so I think you can find something that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling:

```
calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
calendar3.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

you are adding a day to these dates. You are checking if your 'target' date (transposed forward by a day) is between "19:00:00" and "20:00:00 (tomorrow)" and "20:00:00" and "21:00:00 (tomorrow)"

Change your code to :

```
private boolean isBetween(String t1, String t2, String target){
    boolean result = false;
    try{

        Date time1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(t1);
        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar1.setTime(time1);


        Date time2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(t2);
        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar2.setTime(time2);


        Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(target);
        Calendar calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar3.setTime(d);


        Date x = calendar3.getTime();
        if (x.after(calendar1.getTime()) && x.before(calendar2.getTime())) {
            result = true;
            //checkes whether the current time is between 14:49:00 and 20:11:13.

            //Toast.makeText(UserCheckout.this, "The time is between", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    catch (ParseException e){
        result = false;
        Toast.makeText(UserCheckout.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return result;
}
```