# How to make code runnable only for certain period of time

Tags: java

How to make condition like

the code will only run between

***9AM to 10PM*** 
How do I make it on if statement? or whatever method you guys have?

```
if(timeNow >= 9PM && timeNow <= 10PM){
//do coding
}else{
//Code won't execute because its not inside of the scope.
}
```

Comment: More context, please.  Can you post the code you want to run?  Feels more like a scheduler or scripting problem, not Java.

Comment: Can you modify the function/class? Is AspectJ an option?

Comment: I don't know what the proper code for this but I want to make my code only run for between 9AM to 10PM.

Comment: I really don't have idea guys how to do this that is why I am asking for help

Comment: @JohnSmith Could you share more details of the requirement? If not code at least an example of what the code does.

Comment: I edited my post, thats the code I want to make.

Comment: What kind of framework do you use? Do you use any extern library?

Comment: no I only use java, for my javafx project

Comment: Similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/37632445/2804966

Comment: So you want your app to only be able to start between 9am and 10pm? What if it's already running when 10pm hits? Should it get the time from the local device ( then changing the device time would allow you to bypass this limit ) or should it listen to time from an online api ( then you would require an internet connection to be able to start the app ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind time zone, you can use `LocalDateTime`. `getHour()` method will return hour-of-day (0 to 23).

```
int timeNow = LocalDateTime.now().getHour();
if(timeNow >= 9 && timeNow <= 10) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Only available in JDK 8 and later