# how to find my current time lies between today's time and tommorow's time in JAVA

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, logical-operators

I'm trying to determine if the current time e.g. 19:30:00 is between 19:00:00 & 03:00:00 next day, but my code is failing.
my code fails with this condition
can i use date to campare time if yes please let me know how

```java
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class DateUtils {

    // format 24hre ex. 12:12 , 17:15
    private static String  HOUR_FORMAT = "HH:mm";

    private DateUtils() {    }

    public static String getCurrentHour() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdfHour = new SimpleDateFormat(HOUR_FORMAT);
        String hour = sdfHour.format(cal.getTime());
        return hour;
    }

    /**
     * @param  target  hour to check
     * @param  start   interval start
     * @param  end     interval end
     * @return true    true if the given hour is between
     */
    public static boolean isHourInInterval(String target, String start, String end) {
        return ((target.compareTo(start) >= 0)
                && (target.compareTo(end) <= 0));
    }

    /**
     * @param  start   interval start
     * @param  end     interval end
     * @return true    true if the current hour is between
     */
    public static boolean isNowInInterval(String start, String end) {
        return DateUtils.isHourInInterval
            (DateUtils.getCurrentHour(), start, end);
    }

    //    TEST
    public static void main (String[] args) {
      String now = DateUtils.getCurrentHour();
      String start = "14:00";
      String end   = "14:26";
      System. out.println(now + " between " + start + "-" + end + "?");
      System. out.println(DateUtils.isHourInInterval(now,start,end));
      /*
       * output example :
       *   21:01 between 14:00-14:26?
       *   false
       *
       */
    }
}
```

Comment: Tidied up english and added language formatting to code snippet

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead just use `LocalTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a given time lies between two times regardless of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697908/check-if-a-given-time-lies-between-two-times-regardless-of-date)

Comment: In the linked original question I in particular recommend [the answer by Basli Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39712175/5772882) demonstrating the use of java.time.

Comment: You shouldn’t send time strings around between methods in your program. When you get a time into your program as string, parse it into a `LocalTime` first thing and handle it as a `LocalTime` from that point. You don’t even need a formatter: `LocalTime.parse(start)` will do it (and throw an exception if the time string is invalid). Many tings will be simpler once you are using proper time objects rather than strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*java.time.LocalTime* is your friend here. Below is a quick example, sure it can be done somewhat shorter.

```
void test(){
    var tz = ZoneId.of("CET");
    var anyDate = LocalDate.of(2019,12,4);

    var x = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(anyDate, LocalTime.of(18,59)),tz).toInstant();

    System.out.println(testTime(Clock.fixed( ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(anyDate, LocalTime.of(18,59)),tz).toInstant(),tz)));
    System.out.println(testTime(Clock.fixed( ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(anyDate, LocalTime.of(19,01)),tz).toInstant(),tz)));
    System.out.println(testTime(Clock.fixed( ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(anyDate, LocalTime.of(00,00)),tz).toInstant(),tz)));
    System.out.println(testTime(Clock.fixed( ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(anyDate, LocalTime.of(02,59)),tz).toInstant(),tz)));
    System.out.println(testTime(Clock.fixed( ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(anyDate, LocalTime.of(03,01)),tz).toInstant(),tz)));
}

boolean testTime(Clock clock){
    var evening =LocalTime.of(19,00);
    var midnight =LocalTime.of(00,00);
    var night =LocalTime.of(03,00);

    LocalTime wallTime = LocalTime.now(clock);

    return (wallTime.isAfter(evening) && wallTime.isBefore(midnight.minusNanos(1))) ||  (midnight.isBefore(wallTime) && wallTime.isBefore(night)) || wallTime.equals(midnight);

}
```

Comment: Agree that java.time is our friend here (and elsewhere). Don’t rely on three letter time zone abbreviations. Use `ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")` or `ZoneId.of("Europe/Zurich")`. Always *region/city*.