# How to compare current time between two different times?

Tags: android, date, datetime, kotlin

I have a two strings values that represent opening hours of a shop like :

```
val startHour = "08:00"
val endHour = "19:00"
```

I want to check if shop is open by comparing current time between these two times. I tried like below :

```
val hourFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
val startTime = hourFormat.parse(startHour)
val endTime = hourFormat.parse(endHour )
```

but I get parse exception.

Any one has an idea ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697908/check-if-a-given-time-lies-between-two-times-regardless-of-date

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: `val now = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())` and then `if (now.isAfter(LocalTime.parse("08:00")) && now.isBefore(LocalTime.parse("19:00"))) { /* shop is open */ }`.

Comment: I posted a workable example in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68843482/4180169

Please, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Cant you say

val startHour = "08:00:00"

val endHour = "19:00:00"

?

Comment: it worked, but when I see the date it is Jan 01 1970

Answer (score 0):

Your variable doesn't contain :ss that why you have a parse error :)
Then to compare time,  I prefer to compare them as timestamp. Be careful to your GMT if you work in different country.