# Configure listener window depends on time

Tags: java, time

I want to create a method that tells me if i'm between two hours (even if I choose hours from different days)
For example:

```
Current time: 20:00, start: 21:00, end: 23:00 -> returns false
Current time: 22:00, start: 21:00, end: 23:00 -> returns true
Current time: 01:00, start: 21:00, end: 8:00 -> returns true
Current time: 22:00, start: 21:00, end: 20:00 -> returns true
Current time: 05:00, start: 21:00, end: 4:00 -> returns false
```

Is there any simple and clean way to do this?

Comment: look at [isBefore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isBefore-java.time.LocalTime-) and [isAfter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isAfter-java.time.LocalTime-)

Comment: `I want to create a method that tells me if i'm between two hours (even if I choose hours from different days)...Is there any simple and clean way to do this?` - Without the date, the cleanest way is to return `true` in all cases. 

Comment: I chose to close as a duplicate even though the answer given here is better than the accepted answer under the other question. Over there there’s a more thorough [answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39712175/5772882) that I believe deserves your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) for that (since you want it to be independent of the day or timezones or anything like that). It has `isBefore` and similar methods that makes this very simple:

```
public static boolean isBetween(LocalTime before, LocalTime candidate, LocalTime after) {
    return before.isBefore(candidate) && candidate.isBefore(after);
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
System.out.println(isBetween(LocalTime.of(20, 0), LocalTime.now(), LocalTime.of(23, 0));
```

---

### Edit

It seems that you actually want another logic that allows for ranges that overlap a day. Your example for this is:

```
Current time: 01:00, start: 21:00, end: 8:00 -> returns true
```

To make this possible I would introduce the following changes.

First, you can detect this event by simply checking whether `before` is actually *before* `after`. If not, then you have this case. Next, identify whether `now` is on the day of `before` or `after` and then reset the other to either the beginning of the day (`00:00`) or the end of the day (`23:59`) respectively. Afterwards you can compare again by normal means as shown before:

```
public static boolean isBetween(LocalTime before, LocalTime candidate, LocalTime after) {
    // Special handling for day-overlap
    if (before.isAfter(after)) {
        // Identify on which day candidate is and reset the other
        if (before.isBefore(candidate)) {
            after = LocalTime.MAX;
        } else {
            before = LocalTime.MIN;
        }
    }

    return before.isBefore(candidate) && candidate.isBefore(after);
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work for third case :)
It should be something like this
 ```if (endTime.isBefore(startTime)) {
            return (now.isAfter(startTime) && now.isBefore(LocalTime.of(23, 59, 59)))
                    || (now.isBefore(endTime) && now.isAfter(LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0)));
        }
        return now.isAfter(startTime) &&
                now.isBefore(endTime);```

Comment: @domvnski That is because your third case doesnt obey logic and the rules you laid out. `21:00` is not before `01:00`. I get your intention but this is incorrect logic if you want to ignore days. So you actually do want to have day-logic in this case.

Comment: @domvnski I have edited my post accordingly to show you a clean and readable way of doing it.